# Coundown timer syntax error even if the brackets are deleted

Tags: java

Hi I m trying to create a countdown timer however I keep getting syntax error on brackets and on the line setting time.setText and I also get error on the fixed schedule line as well a (syntax error) I have deleted the brackets to see if the error goes but it creates more errors the code is written below.

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

public class timerr {

 String settingTimer;

  Timer timerrr = new Timer();

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    private int i = 0;

    public void run(){
        if (i <= 30) {
        settingTime.setText("" + i++);
        System.out.println(i);

   timerrr.scheduleAtFixedRate (task, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

These are fundamental mistakes:

1. TimerTask is an Abstract class; this means that it cannot be instantiated and needs to be implemented.

solution:  extend TimerTask and implement the necessary methods:

```
YourClass extends TimerTask
{
    @override 
    public void run() { //your code here }
}
```

2. You need to enclose a code block inside a method in your main class:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){ 

     TimerTask tt = new YourClass();

     //rest of your code here
     Timer time = new Timer();

     time.schedule(tt, 1000, 1 * 1000);

   }
   ```